# Why “formed” can sit after “exist” in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Some works of fiction achieve remarkable popularity by creating entire alternative worlds that seem to exist fully formed.

What does exist fully formed mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "exist fully formed" means that the fictional world seems to already exist in a fully formed state. That is, the world created by piece of fiction is so complete or extensive that it *feels* like that world was not written by an author, but rather, the world already existed and the author is giving the reader a peek into that world.

For example, the society in the Star Wars franchise may seem to "exist fully formed" because the fictional society and geography of the universe in which Star Wars takes place is so detailed and complex that it seems like the authors and directors who made the Star Wars universe didn't make it up. Instead it seems like the Star Wars universe is a real place and society that already exists and the movies act like a window into a fully formed, very real world.